# Not able to retrieve full file using wget

Tags: xml, linux, unix, ubuntu, wget

I am trying to download feed.xml from one source. I am successfully able to download it in windows. While its failing in linux/unix machine.

These are the Request headers and response headers on my windows.

```
Response Header: Connection keep-alive
Content-Disposition attachment; filename="feeds.xml";
Content-Type text/xml
Date Wed, 24 Dec 2014 04:18:59 GMT
Expires Mon, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Server nginx/1.2.3
Transfer-Encoding chunked
X-Powered-By PHP/5.3.13

Request: Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection keep-alive
Host www2.xyz.com
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
```

My linux/unix code/command to download the file from the url.

```
wget --no-check-certificate -O  feed.xml 'http://www2.xyz.com/feed.php?id=XXX-YYY&pass=*******'
```

In windows its size is 980MB and linux its size is 12MB .If i am trying to do the `less feed.xml` then it is showing this message in  linux/Unix.

```
"feed.xml" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
```

I have tried setting the header too and it gave me the response like this but not downloaded the full file.

```
  wget  -S --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip"  'http://www2.xyz.com'

  Connecting to www2.XYZ.com|***.**.**.**|:80... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response...

  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx/1.2.3
  Date: Wed, 24 Dec 2014 03:50:51 GMT
  Content-Type: text/xml
  Content-Length: 12252156
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13
  Expires: Mon, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
  Content-encoding: gzip
  Content-disposition: attachment; filename="feeds.xml";
  Length: 12252156 (12M) [text/xml]
```

How can i resolve this issue and can download feed.xml in linux .Please help.

Comment: What do you use in windows to download ?

Comment: It is properly downloaded in windows without any issue and i can open the file too.

Comment: please be consistent, your title says feed.xml, yet code says abc.xml and feed.php (among others). Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header info shows the content-encoding is gzip. Could be that gzip on windows expanded this for you, and on Linux it didn't and you're stuck with the compressed file.

Try doing this:

```
gzcat feed.xml > feed_expanded.xml
```

or if you don't have gzcat:

```
mv feed.xml feed.xml.gz; gunzip feed.xml.gz
```

Comment: Awesome. It worked. I spent more than 2/3 hrs on this. Thanks

Comment: Next time, think of using `file file.xml` to figure out what it is